# Unable to invoke action from ui:button component in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, lightninginput

Could you please help in solving this issue?. I am unable to invoke controller action from ui:button press event. Code is below.

Controller.js

```
({
    displayName : function(cmp, event) {
       alert("Hi");
    }
})
```

UI Component:

```
<ui:button label="Display Name" press="{!c.displayName}" ></ui:button>
```

When button pressed, all i got is 
**"This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Unknown controller action 'displayName'
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:LCInput}"**

I am unable to move further on learning path due to this simple issue. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I ran the same code and it worked for me. Did you save the controller code?. If not post the full markup and controller code.

Comment: @RedDevil THanks for quick response. I am unable to include <aura:component> into my post.  Possible please edit the post with  <aura:component > wrap the <ui:button>. That's it. So I  am not sure why ui:button action  is not working for me . I  have tried in various browsers too and all my attempts ends in vain.

Comment: Can you check if you have put the controller function in helper. I dont see any error in your code but when i place the controller code in helper and preview it i get the same error you got. On the right check if your code is in controller or helper. It should be in controller

Comment: @RedDevil You are right. I had referred my app controller instead of component's one. Just noticed the names - My component name - LCInput.cmp and controller is LCInputAppController.js.  Fixed it and working now. Very sorry for posting this and ruined your time. But very grateful to you for your time and help.